# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

I'm try running a DSC configuration in azure automations, but it get's suspended with following exception:

> "The running command stopped because the preference variable
>   "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: A
>   positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
>   'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.

The code I'm running is :

```
Configuration DomainJoin{

$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "azurelogin" 
Login-AzureRmAccount $cred
Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'xDSCDomainjoin'
$dscDomainAdmin = Get-AzureRmAutomationCredential -Name "GSY admin" -ResourceGroupName "RG-DC-ROCS" -AutomationAccountName "RocsAutomation"
$dscDomainName = Get-AzureRMAutomationVariable -Name "dscDomainName" -ResourceGroupName "RG-DC-ROCS" -AutomationAccountName "RocsAutomation"
#PSDscAllowDomainUser = $True

node localhost
{
    xDSCDomainjoin JoinDomain
    {
        Domain = $dscDomainName
        Credential = $dscDomainAdmin
    }
}
}
```

Any idea how I can solve the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to change:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount $cred
```

To:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

It seems that `-Credential` has to be named to be used.

Comment: I gave it a try and now I get a new exception:
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Invalid MOF definition for node 'localhost': Exception calling "ValidateInstanceText" with "1" argument(s): "Convert property 'Credential' value from type 'STRING' to type 'INSTANCE' failed At line:17, char:2 Buffer: ame = "DomainJoin"; };^ insta "


Not sure what is wrong with this:
Credential = $dscDomainAdmin